# How do you remove all vendor-prefixes from entire file quickly?

Tags: css, file, sass, vendor-prefix

I got a CSS file which has so many **vendor-prefixes** *(-webkit -moz etc)*.

And those vendor-prefixes makes the file much bigger.

I cannot remove vendor prefix one by one, Because it can take a lot of time.
Is there any tools or tricks to remove **vendor-prefixes** from entire with one click?

Comment: Find and Replace in your text editor? But how much bigger are we talking about? It probably will make little to no difference.

Comment: Before removing you should know why it is there :) [Browser Compatibility]

Comment: I sure know why it is there. Using prefixfree.js will make css much more maintainable. By the way a part of visitor of my website are still using 4 mbps speed network.

Comment: @Jackwintung : what if someone disables the `js` in browser.... *just a thought*!! ??

Comment: @NoobEditor Yeah. You are right. I guess it's better to keeps vendor-prefixes there.

Answer (score 9):

A nice feature of [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) is that it also removes unneeded prefixes from your CSS. You can try it online here:

http://autoprefixer.github.io/

To remove all prefixes, leave the "Filter" textbox at the bottom empty.

Comment: To remove ALL prefixes you can leave the "Filter" textbox blank.

Comment: it adds the prefixes. but how do you clean the prefixes?

Comment: @NorbertKardos - In addition to adding needed prefixes, it also *removes unneeded prefixes*. Try the link in the answer: Paste your CSS, clear the "Browserslist" text box and hit "Apply".

Answer (score 8):

@Sphinxxx's `last 1 version` answer is, [as stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36554256/1341949), only “almost” correct. To remove ***all*** vendor prefixes, set the [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) filter to `>100%` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, 
 
I was trying to remove all browser **vendor prefixes** from entire file **at a time**.
I found an awesome tool **postcss-remove-prefixes**. Which did my work easily in just seconds.

**You can find this tool here** [postcss-remove-prefix](https://github.com/johno/postcss-remove-prefixes)

I assume that you have installed **NodeJs and NPM** on your system.

***Here is the process to use this tool*** 
`npm i -g postcss-remove-prefixes`

**Then use this tool from CMD as** 
`remove-prefixes input.css`        
This will remove Vendor prefixes from your file

`remove-prefixes input.css output.css` 
This will remove Vendor prefixes from your file and generates output as new file.

**:) Enjoy**

Answer (score -1):

This [javascript function](https://github.com/CheeseFrog/JS-DeVendorCSS) I hosted on github does what you're looking for. 
`var t = DeVendorCSS("transform")` returns, for example, in a webkit browser without "transform" support, but with prefixed support, an array `["webkit", "webkitTransform", "-webkit-transform"]` for use in *inline CSS rules*, such as `e.style[t[1]]="translateY(5px)"`. The actual value "translateY" has to be compatible cross-vendor for this to work in this example (though, if not, get funky with the vendor id given as t[0]).